# Getting undefined when using import() to dynamically import an instantiated class object

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am getting `undefined` when I try to read any properties on my instantiated class object that I get from using `import()`. Not sure what else to try besides this below...

Code in one of my components:

```
import { IModel } from '@/core/types'

// code omitted for brevity

const [model, setModel] = useState<IModel | null>(null)

useEffect(() => {
    ;(async () => {
        const data: IModel = await import(`../../core/models/${instance.component.name}Model.ts`)
        setModel(_ => data)
    })()
}, [instance.component.name])
```

Here `instance.component.name` would have a value of `ToDoList` located at `<project-root>/src/core/models/ToDoListModel.ts`. The code doing the import is located at `<project-root>/src/components/MyComponent/MyComponent.tsx`.

My model:

```
import { IModel } from '@/core/types'

class ToDoListModel implements IModel {
    public name: string
    public isDropContainer: boolean
    public requiredProps: string[]

    private _dropBlacklist: string[]

    constructor() {
        this.name = 'ToDoList'
        this.isDropContainer = false
        this.requiredProps = []
        this._dropBlacklist = ['Test']
    }

    public isDragAllowed = (): boolean => {
        return true
    }

    public isDropAllowed = (component: IModel): boolean => {
        return this.isDropContainer && !this._dropBlacklist.includes(component.name)
    }
}

const model = new ToDoListModel()

export default model
```

When I try to `console.log(model?.name)` I get `undefined`. No errors in the console which tells me the import is resolving the module just fine.

Comment: What does `console.log(data)` show?

Comment: Your code looks correct, where did you run `console.log`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wanted to assign `default` to the variable, not the entire module

```
const data: IModel = (await import(`../../core/models/${instance.component.name}Model.ts`)).default
setModel(_ => data)
```

Comment: This was exactly it.